# How to connect to SSAS instance from SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, ssms

I have recently installed full sql server 2008 (trial version), for doing a research on SSAS.
I created a SSAS project (with sqlserver business intelligence studio), deployed locally (where sql server instance is) with success.

The problem is that I dont see it in databases list with SSMS.

Is there a special way to connect to SSAS instance? Because looking at [link text](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1995) I see SSMS opened with other structure in object explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a connection (File -> Connect Object Explorer) ... just make sure that *Analysis Services* is selected in the "Server Type" drop down, instead of *Database Engine*.

Comment: Thanks, in fact the problem was the installed version of SSMS (the "basic" one instead of "complete" one) - the "Analysis services" wasnt available in the drop down.