# Unable to connect to SSAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figure out how to fix this but no luck.
An asp.net report that runs an ssas report is failing for invalid datasource.
When i checked the report and tested the connection it fails.
At start i found that the sql server analysis service in the sql management is not running, it was disabled.
I put it on automatic and restarted the pc, so it started running, but the report is still failing.
I am not very good at sql server settings and trouble shooting, can you please point me to where i should be looking next?

Comment: First and foremost I would check everything locally (not from remote computers). This is just to make sure that there are not any other problems such as connectivity problems, firewalls, router problems, etc. So, on the locally installed SSMS I would check if you can connect to SSAS using `.` as `Server Name`.

Comment: The Datasource connection string used by the report is already using . as Server name and fails to connect locally. Other than the fact that SSAS wasn't running I can't think of anything else :(

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204466/how-to-connect-to-ssas-instance-from-ssms or look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266333/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-analysis-services-even-though-it-seems-to-be-runnin Which version do you have installed: Enterprise, Express, ....?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check them and hope I will find a solution.